# Scheduling audio notification, when app is in background

Tags: ios

I'm developing navi-like app.

I have to play sound notification at scheduled time. I have enabled audio background mode, but obviously I cant use `NSTimer` for this.

What could I use to schedule audio notification at specified time, so it fires even if the app goes into background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explore [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html), using which you can set notification at particular interval and also it is possible to set custom sound, [see this example for custom sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188848/uilocalnotification-custom-sound), files for your app.

like

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *dateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComp setDay:YourDay];
[dateComp setHour:YourHour];
[dateComp setMinute:YourMinute];

NSLog(@"Year: %i, Month: %i, Day: %i, Time:%i:%i\n",[dateComp year], [dateComp month], 
                    [dateComp day], [dateComp hour], [dateComp minute]);
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
notif.fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComp];
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

notif.alertBody = YourAlertBody;
notif.soundName = @"fireburn.caf";
```

Note : Above code credit goes to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188848/uilocalnotification-custom-sound)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UILocalNotification` for this task.